# Using async in a method in a chain

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var txt = await GetTask();
}

static Task<string> GetTask()
{
    return GetText();
}

static async Task<string> GetText()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "result";
}
```

Is asynchrony breaking in my case?
Do I need to make the `GetTask` async method?

Comment: No, The GetTask returns the Task from the GetText directly.

Comment: Don't think of async methods, *specifically* as being methods that are marked `async`. async methods are *any* method that returns a `Task` that represents the work that may (or may not) be completed yet. *how* the method produces that `Task` is entirely an implementation detail of that method.

Comment: Which of the two `GetTask`?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Answer (score 2):

If it's a simple forward, no you don't, if there is a chance something in the *code block* could go wrong, you would have to handle exceptions with `Task.FromException` to push the exception onto the task (in the way the *async and await pattern* would), in which case it's probably easier to just use the `async` keyword and `await` the *awaitables* for a small performance hit of the `IAsyncStateMachine`.